# Tools to help with 2d game design?

Tags: designers, games

I am a game designer and I need tools to help me 
not like adobe photoshop and illustrator or unity or any of those

something to help me create screenshots/game icon 
something like: https://theapplaunchpad.com/examples/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is wrong with the app you linked to?  Why don't you want to use Photoshop or Illustrator?  What is wrong with those solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you ask for special tools for creating screenshots when you are actually linking to such a tool: *AppLaunchpad*. Why isn't that app suitable for you? It seems to do exactly what you ask for.

But no special tools are really needed. Any image editor can be used for this. I don't understand why you reject using Photoshop. It's just 3 images layered on top of each other.

Take a background image:

[image]

Place an image of a phone on top:

[image]

Place a screenshot on top and scale it to fit the screen:

[image]

Rotate the phone with the screenshot and add text and other details:

[image]